# What is a Collection in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was in a job interview and describing how I laid out some UITextFields and UIButtons in Interface Builder and the interviewer asked me "Why did you do that instead of using a Collection?"

I have no idea what he means by "Collection", can someone please explain?

Comment: In general, for all languages, a "collection" is the equivalent of NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet, etc.

Comment: Because you are using interface builder, I assume the question was "Why did you create 10 outlets when you could have created an outlet collection?"

Comment: why didn't you ask him?

Comment: One suggestion when you have a question of this sort would be to try searching Xcode's Documentation and API Reference. In this case a search for **Collection Topics** would yield a link to the *Collections Programming Topics* guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only think that they meant an `IBOutletCollection`.

You wouldn't really use them to layout anything though.

An `IBOutletCollection` just lets you assign multiple buttons, labels, etc... to a single array of objects.

You can then iterate the objects instead of having to have multiple properties, one for each button, label, image view, etc...

It's an odd question from the interviewer.

Comment: "It's an odd question from the interviewer." Why odd? If an interviewee showed me a design where, for the sake of argument, he had declared ten outlets named textField1...textFieldn, I would've asked exactly the same thing.

Comment: @jlehr OK, possibly. Just seemed odd when related to laying out buttons. It's definitely a valid question in that context though.

Answer (score 1):

He could have meant a UICollectionView or an [IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/). I'm guessing the latter. If so, probably you were making outlets for each button even though they are conceptually similar, so he was wondering why you didn't just make a collection of buttons to reference them all.